# Ads show in AVD but not in genymotion and app on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I am trying to use admob in a code but when I run the app on a real device or in genymotion , I got no ads, and when I run it in the AVD (emulator of android studio) I got the test ads saying that I have succesfully did it.

I don't now where I missed up and I don't know which part of code I have to send so you can help me.

I've tried to chek my Unit Code of admob but it's look correct.

Comment: Check ad id and app id also check it has internet permissions and internet is available

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this test Unit ID and test your app on real device

```
Banner: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
Interstitial: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910
```

If no ad appears  change your app package name 
Hope it helps